# jQuery in an ASP.net MVC application using Master Pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get simple jQuery to execute on my Content page with no luck below is what I am trying to do:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function() {
           alert("hi");
       });   
   </script>

</asp:Content>
```

I have also tried getting the following to work:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function onload()
       {
          $("#myDiv").css("border", "1px solid green");
       }
   </script>

   <div id="myDive">
      Hello
   </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: you should put the jquery script reference in your master page HEAD section instead of on the content page (i realize you probably are just putting it here for an example and probably already know this)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It may be that the JQuery file can't be found, try this for the script reference:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content ("~/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The Url.Content will build the correct path regardless of whether the app is running in the root or a sub-directory.

Also, if you've installed the hot-fix for the JS intellisense, you can use this in addition to the above:

```
<% if (false) { %>
    <!-- Don't wrap this is a Url.Content call, it's like this so we get intellisense! -->
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```

**Edit:**

Since the release of the RC 1 Refresh, there's been a know bug about placing elements with code blocks in the header, Philip Haacked has a nice [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/27/controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-issue-with-asp.net-mvc-rc1.aspx) about solving it...

**Edit 2:**

Apparently this has been fixed since RC 2 was released...

> • Code nuggets that are direct children of the head element do not cause an exception if the runat="server" attribute is added to them.

**Edit 3:**

The hot-fix referenced earlier is only applicable to VS2008 and is available [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736) - check out the blog post by the VS Web Dev Team [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/02/08/jscript-intellisense-working-with-jquery.aspx) for details. VS2010 has it built in.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good tip for fixing Master Pages in an MVC site that uses **Areas**.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the javascript references in your Master Page.  Then you don't have to worry about attempting to load the scripts multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Have to use  to publish the site right, but is a pain when you work with a designer that just know how to use photoshop and dreamweaver