# CSS and Javascript relative path confusion in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My javascript paths work on this page:
http://localhost:53049/

But not on this page:
http://localhost:53049/Home/Messages

The reason is that the relative paths are different, the former requires ("js/...") and the latter requires ("../../js/...").

I'm including my javascript in my Site.Master file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js") %>"></script>
```

How do I get around this relative path madness, i.e. what is the best practice way in ASP.NET MVC to set CSS/Javascript paths in the Site.Master so that they work for each view no matter how deep that view's URL happens to be.

**ADDENDUM:**

It seems that for the Index view, any path will work, strangely:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
```

But for any other pages (pages with a deeper URL), none of these work.

What's going on here? How can we set the Javascript path once in Site.Master and they work for all pages?

**ADDENUM II:**

It turned out to only be a problem with the jqgrid javascript file (not the jquery file), apparently inside that file it is referencing other javascript files and gets confused:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content ("~/js/jquery.jqGrid.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: we can't see things posted from your localhost machine.

Comment: tres LOL - hadn't even noticed

Comment: I know (hope) you can't see them on my local machine, I just don't know how to make the http's non-links with this editor. Point is that the paths don't work if there are directories in the URL.

Comment: Good point about the **Index** View because everything appears to work fine until you move to another Action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use the Url.Content method call to make sure that the paths are correctly set.

Examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371591/jquery-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-using-master-pages#371603).

Answer (score 13):

Regarding paths used in CSS documents:

**/Content/site.css**

```
Body {background-image:url('background.jpg');}
```

Relative paths in CSS documents are related to the CSS document, not the document being displayed.

This information saved me some headaches.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the javascript to use a forward slash at the beginning, like "/js/jquery.jqGrid.js" This will set them to use the root domain instead of relative pathing.

Comment: Of course this will only work if the files truly live in a location off the root of the site.  For instance, developing in a virtual directory but deploying in the root would cause this method to fail during development.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for jqGrid: open the file jquery.jqGrid.js and locate the line:

```
var pathtojsfiles = "js/"; // need to be ajusted
```

As the comment says, you need to edit that path, e.g. for a typical ASP.NET MVC app,

```
var pathtojsfiles = "/Scripts/js/"; // need to be ajusted
```

Comment: when running locally in a virtual directory/application, the URL will be /MyApp/Scripts/js/. any suggestions on what to do then? I'd hate to turn the js file into a view just so I can use URL.Content, and I'm not too crazy about relying on changes to lmhosts etc. any alternatives?

Comment: Short answer: I switched to using slickgrid, which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `runat="server"` and to specify the absolute path like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" runat="server"  src="~/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>]`