# asp.net mvc and jQuery with "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I've got an asp.net mvc view with at the end the following javascript code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(
            function () {
              alert("This is a test");
            });
  </script>
```

The alert doesn't show when loading the page.
I've got the following error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

This is the  section of the Site.Master:

```
  <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="../../Content/Controls.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="../../Content/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Does anyone has an idea why I got this error?
Even when I delete the alert, I've got this error.

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your scripts are included correctly, for example what you have:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That may be valid for where the `.master` is, but an invalid *relative* path to where the page is, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435769/css-and-javascript-relative-path-confusion-in-asp-net-mvc) for setting relative paths *to the current page* in your master.

Answer (score 1):

The problemn is solved by using:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content ("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="<%= Url.Content ("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="<%= Url.Content ("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.js") %>" type="text/javascript" />
```